# How to switch off the django debug screen

Tags: python, django

I have django project.

In my development, when error happens like not import modules... etc.

It shows the error on the browser, but I don't want to show that in production.

Where can I switch off the debug mode???

Comment: In the `settings.py` file you set `DEBUG` to `False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `settings.py` file has a [**`DEBUG`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG). You will furthermore need to specify the [**`ALLOWED_HOSTS`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS). You can set this to `False`:

```
# settings.py

# …
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mywebsite.com']
# …
```

Note that some tooling of Django is not done when you work in a production environment, like serving static files. You will need to configure nginx/apache/… for that. For more information, see the [*Deploying static files* section in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Answer (score 2):

here you should enter False or True in way your need. if my answer is correct pls check it for answered

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'this is security key'

 # Turn off When Project Will published for use!
DEBUG = True

 ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*] <-- this for plesk and Cpanel


 # Application definition

 INSTALLED_APPS = [ ' Your current app',' Your Seccond app ']
```

Comment: ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] not [ * ]